# App freezes android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation, android-screen

I have developed application which works in Portrait mode only. However, I am facing very weird problem only for device **Samsung S Tab 2560 x 1600 pixels (~288 ppi pixel density) 10.5'inch**.

I have a screen designed this way

Activity - > MAIN Fragment (ViewPager) -> No . of fragments [A, B...]

On Fragment B, I have a list. Now, the problem is when my app is opened or running & due to timeouts device gets locked after unlocking list gets cleared & app jumps to MAIN Fragment & goes in freezed mode.

AFAIU, the problem is with screen orientation gets changes when it goes in locked state.